# Android service lifecycle

Tags: android

In one case, one `service` being started by another component runs on the main UI thread of that component, while the service may live even that component is destroyed, so my question is where to execute the `service` if the component started that `service` is stopped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, when you call `startService()`, the service will remain running until you call `stopService()` from another component or `stopSelf()` from the service itself. And `onStartCommand()` will always [run on UI thread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand%28android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int%29).

If the service is running, subsequent calls to `startService()` will not create another instance of your service but run `onStartCommand()` again on the running one. This is slightly different if you are binding your component to a service. In this case, the service is automatically destroyed when you unbind all components. For more details on this, see: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Lifecycle.

In addition, note that there different ways to keep a service running, depending on what [you return from the `onStartCommand()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ServiceLifecycle):

> START_STICKY is used for services that are explicitly started and
>   stopped as needed, while START_NOT_STICKY or START_REDELIVER_INTENT
>   are used for services that should only remain running while processing
>   any commands sent to them.

To answer your question specifically, where and how to start your service depends on what exactly you want to do with it. If the component that started the service stopped, it is up to you to either 1) get a new reference to the service from another component and stop it or 2) stop the service from the service itself. But the service won't stop because the component did. Unless you are binding it to the service.